# ¿Cómo corregir el error 'Cannot read properties of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, html, jdeveloper

Este es el error que me sale cuando ejecuto el index

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at setWeatherData (index.js:12:32)
    at index.js:6:26
setWeatherData @ index.js:12
(anonymous) @ index.js:6
Promise.then (async)
fetchData @ index.js:6
```

Acá dejo una parte del código que creo que es lo que me esta dando el error

```
const setWeatherData = data => {
    console.log(data);
    const weatherData = {
      location: data.name,
      description: data.Weather[0].main,
      humidity: data.main.humidity,
      pressure: data.main.pressure,
      temperature: data.main.temp,
      date: 'data',
    }
```

Estoy creando una aplicación del clima, cuando lo ejecute esperaba que me saliera, Localidad,Clima,Temperatura, etc.

Es raro porque estoy siguiendo un video de youtube y esta igual como lo hice, aunque puede haberme pasado de olvidarme de declarar algo o algún ;

Si alguien tiene idea sobre el tema, le agradezco ;)

Comment: Posiblemente tu parámetro data o Weather este undefined. De donde viene ese dato?

Comment: Agrega el contenido de data, el error dice que `data.Weather[0]`, es indefinido esto quiere decir que `data.Weather` no tiene contenido (.length=0) o no tiene indice 0. Debes revisar que `data.Weather` sea un arreglo y que tenga contenido para poder acceder a el.

Comment: en qué momento te sale ese error?

Answer (score 1):

El error indica lo siguiente:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

Seguramente es en la siguinte linea de codigo:

```
description: data.Weather[0].main
```

Debes de verificar que la propiedad de "Weather" es un array. En tu caso, es undefined, por lo que también deberías de validar el caso en que este atributo no lo regrese la API.